Derived completeness of the inverse perfection
Fix a prime number $p$, and let $R$ be a ring of positive characteristic $p$. Consider the inverse perfection of $R$, which is defined as the inverse limit
$$
R^\flat = \varprojlim(\cdots \xrightarrow{F} R \xrightarrow{F} R \xrightarrow{F} R),
$$
where $F\colon R\to R$ denotes the Frobenius endomorphism. It can be checked that $R^\flat$ is perfect, i.e., the Frobenius endomorphism on $R^\flat$ is bijective. Here is my question:
$R^\flat$ is derived $f$-adically complete for any element $f$ in the kernel of the $0$-th projection $R^\flat \to R$ ?
This question occurred to me when I study the relation between perfect prisms and (integral) perfectoid rings. Also I know that, as $R^\flat$ is perfect, its derived $f$-completeness is equivalent to its classically $f$-completeness (see Bhatt's lecture note for prismatic cohomology).

Derived completeness is defined by the vanishing of a limit, so it is stable under inverse limits. It is then enough to show that each copy of R appearing in the inverse limit defining $R^\flat$ is derived $f$-complete. But $f$ is nilpotent in each of these copies, so the claim is clear. (As $R^\flat$ is an inverse limit of separated modules, it is separated; since separedness + derived completeness implies classical completeness, we also get classical completeness as in Sawin's more explicit answer.)

An element $x$ of $R^\flat$ is a sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots$ of elements of $R$ such that $x_i=x_{i+1}^p$. We have $f_1=0$ so $f_k^n=0$ if $n \geq p^k$. Thus if $a$ and $b$ are congruent mod $f^{p^k}$ then $a_1=b_1,\dots, a_k=b_k$. From this it is clear that the map from $R^\flat$ to its $f$-adic completion is injective: If two elements are congruent modulo $f^{p^k}$ then their first entries agree so if they are congruent modulo all powers of $f$ then they are equal.
To get surjectivity, any element in the $f$-adic completion may be expressed as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i f^i$ for some $a_i\in R^\flat$. Since $a_{i} f^i$ has the first $k$ components vanishing for $i \geq p^k$, this sum converges in the inverse limit topology of $R^\flat$ to a limit $a_\infty$. We want to check that $a_\infty$ is also the $f$-adic limit. We have
$$ a_\infty=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_i f^i + \sum_{i=k}^\infty a_i f^i = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_i f^i + f^k\sum_{i=k}^\infty a_i f^{i-k} $$ with infinite the sums taken in the inverse limit topology, so $a_\infty$ is congruent to $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_i f^i$ modulo $f^k$ for all $k$ and thus gives the $f$-adic limit as desired. The key point is that multiplication by an element commutes with sums in the inverse limit topology, which is clear since multiplication by an element commutes with sums in each of the rings we are taking an inverse limit in.

I'm not quite sure "the inverse limit topology." What topologies are endowed with R?

@Zuka The discrete topology. A sequence converges in the inverse limit topology if and only if its projection to each object in the diagram being limited over is eventually constant, so a series converges if and only if its projection to each object is eventually zero.
